# Can I catch exit() and die() messages?

Tags: php, die

I'd like to be able to catch `die()` and `exit()` messages. Is this possible? I'm hoping for something similar to `set_error_handler` and `set_exception_handler`. I've looked at `register_shutdown_function()` but it seems to contain no context for the offending `die()` and `exit()` calls.

I realize that `die()` and `exit()` are bad ways to handle errors. I am not looking to be told not to do this. :) I am creating a generic system and want to be able to gracefully log `exit()` and `die()` if for some reason someone (not me) decides this is a good idea to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As best as I can tell this is not really possible. Some of the solutions posted here may work but they require a lot of additional work or many dependencies. There is no way to easily and reliable trap the die() and exit() messages.

Comment: Well, it is possible by rewriting the script while you read it. The following example tokenizes the input and rewrites exit($code) and die $code to php_exit($code): EDIT: stackoverflow doesn't allow me to add code here, see this post for inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182968/token-get-all-back-to-php-source-how-to

Answer (score 16):

Yes you can, but you need **ob_start**, **ob_get_contents**, **ob_end_clean** and **register_shutdown_function**

```
function onDie(){
    $message = ob_get_contents(); // Capture 'Doh'
    ob_end_clean(); // Cleans output buffer
    callWhateverYouWant();
}
register_shutdown_function('onDie');
//...
ob_start(); // You need this to turn on output buffering before using die/exit
@$dumbVar = 1000/0 or die('Doh'); // "@" prevent warning/error from php
//...
ob_end_clean(); // Remember clean your buffer before you need to use echo/print
```

Answer (score 7):

According to the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php), shutdown functions should still be notified when die() or exit() is called.

> [Shutdown functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) and [object destructors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.destructor) will always be executed even if exit() is called.

It doesn't seem to be possible to get the status sent in exit($status). Unless you can use output buffering to capture it, but I'm not sure how you'd know when to call `ob_start()`.

Comment: I guess the OP's problem is that he would like to be able to retrieve the error message from the shutdown function.

Comment: The shutdown function is being called, but I am not sure if/how I can get the exit/die context at that point. For that matter, it wasn't clear if I'd even know if exit/die is the reason for the shutdown function being called. (it looked like the shutdown function gets called on die, but it gets called when the process terminates after a successful run as well...)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe  [override_function()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.override-function.php) could be interesting, if APD is available

Comment: This is an interesting idea! Hoping for a better non-APD solution, though.

Comment: I don't think that will work. `die` and `exit` are language constructs, not functions.

Comment: @Dr.Molle Can you repost the link again, the old one is 404.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use custom error handling instead? If not, you could always use LD_PRELOAD and C Code injection to catch it :) Or recompile php with your customizations :P

Answer (score 0):

If you use the single point of entry method. (index.php) I can recommend this for your error handling:

**Short version:**

```
ob_start();
register_shutdown_function('shutdownHandler');

include('something');

define(CLEAN_EXIT, true);

function shutdownHandler() {
    if(!defined("CLEAN_EXIT") || !CLEAN_EXIT) {
        $msg = "Script stopped unexpectedly: ".ob_get_contents();
        //Handle premature die()/exit() here
    }
}
```

**Additional steps and more detailed:**

Roughly my way of doing it. I have even more going on than I show here (handling database transactions/rollback/sending e-mails/writing logs/displaying friendly error messages/user error reporting/etc), but this is the basic idea behind all of it).
Hope it helps someone.

```
<?php

    //Some initialization

    //starting output buffering. (fatalErrorHandler is optional, but I recommend using it) 
    ob_start('fatalErrorHandler');

    //Execute code right at the end. Catch exit() and die() here. But also all other terminations inside PHPs control
    register_shutdown_function('shutdownHandler');

    //handling other errors: Also optional
    set_error_handler('errorHandler');



    try {
        //Include of offensive code
        include(...);
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        //Handling exception. Be careful to not raise exceptions here again. As you can end up in a cycle. 
    }

    //Code reached this point, so it was a clean exit.
    define(CLEAN_EXIT, true);


    //Gets called when the script engine shuts down.
    function shutdownHandler() {

        $status = connection_status();

        $statusText = "";

        switch ($status) {
            case 0:
                if (!defined("CLEAN_EXIT") || !CLEAN_EXIT) {
                                    $msg = "Script stopped unexpectedly: ".ob_get_contents();
                    //Handle premature die()/exit() here
                }
                else {
                    //Clean exit. Just return
                    return;
                }
            case 1: $statusText = "ABORTED (1)"; break;
            case 2: $statusText = "TIMEOUT (2)"; break;
            case 3: $statusText = "ABORTED & TIMEOUT (3)"; break;

            default : $statusText = "UNKNOWN ($status)"; break;
        }

        //Handle other exit variants saved in $statusText here ob_get_contents() can have additional useful information here
    }

    // error handler function  (This is optional in your case)
    function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {

        $msg = "[$errno] $errstr\nOn line $errline in file $errfile";

        switch ($errno) {
            case E_ERROR:               $msg = "[E_ERROR] ".$msg;               break;
            case E_WARNING:             $msg = "[E_WARNING] ".$msg;             break;
            case E_PARSE:               $msg = "[E_PARSE] ".$msg;               break;
            case E_NOTICE:              $msg = "[E_NOTICE] ".$msg;              break;
            case E_CORE_ERROR:          $msg = "[E_CORE_ERROR] ".$msg;          break;
            case E_CORE_WARNING:        $msg = "[E_CORE_WARNING] ".$msg;        break;
            case E_COMPILE_ERROR:       $msg = "[E_COMPILE_ERROR] ".$msg;       break;
            case E_COMPILE_WARNING:     $msg = "[E_COMPILE_WARNING] ".$msg;     break;
            case E_USER_ERROR:          $msg = "[E_USER_ERROR] ".$msg;          break;
            case E_USER_WARNING:        $msg = "[E_USER_WARNING] ".$msg;        break;
            case E_USER_NOTICE:         $msg = "[E_USER_NOTICE] ".$msg;         break;
            case E_STRICT:              $msg = "[E_STRICT] ".$msg;              break;
            case E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR:   $msg = "[E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR] ".$msg;   break;
            case E_DEPRECATED:          $msg = "[E_DEPRECIATED] ".$msg;         break;
            case E_USER_DEPRICIATED:    $msg = "[E_USER_DEPRICIATED] ".$msg;    break;
            default:                    $msg = "[UNKNOWN] ".$msg;               break;
        }

        //Handle Normal error/notice/warning here. 
        $handled = ...

        if ($handled)
            return true; //handled. Proceed execution
        else
            throw Exception($msg); //Be careful. this might quickly become cyclic. Be sure to have code that catches and handles exceptions. Else die() here after logging/reporting the error.

    }

    function fatalErrorHandler(&$buffer) {

        $matches = null;
        //Checking if the output contains a fatal error
        if (preg_match('/<br \/>\s*<b>([^<>].*)error<\/b>:(.*)<br \/>$/', $buffer, $matches) ) {

            $msg = preg_replace('/<.*?>/','',$matches[2]);

            //Handle Fatal error here

            return "There was an unexpected situation that resulted in an error. We have been informed and will look into it."
         }

         //No fatal exception. Return buffer and continue
         return $buffer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Catching exits is useful in automated tests. The way I do it is I throw a special runtime exception instead of calling exit directly.

```php
<?php

class CatchableExit extends RuntimeException
{
}

class Quitter
{
    public function run($i)
    {
        echo "Quitter called with \$i = $i \n";
        throw new CatchableExit();
    }
}

class Runner
{
    public function run()
    {
        trigger_error('I am a harmless warning', E_USER_WARNING);
        trigger_error('And I am a notice', E_USER_NOTICE);
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            $q = new Quitter();
            try {
                $q->run($i);
            } catch (CatchableExit $e) {
            }
        }
    }
}

function exception_handler(Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof CatchableExit) {
        exit();
    }
}

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');

$runner = new Runner();
$runner->run();
```

Answer (score -4):

yes: write a function and use that instead.

```
function kill($msg){
    // Do your logging..
    exit($msg);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but this is not helpful at all. I want to catch exit() and die() in the event that some code I have not written calls them.

Comment: i know but that is the closest you can get to it, just one new function and a simple search and replace from exit and die to kill..