# token_get_all, back to php source, how to?

Tags: php

I want to analize a source code (with `token_get_all()`) make some modification (for example, turning all `private` to `public`, get rid of `final`, etc), and save the source code but keeping the same formatting, tabulators, etc. Is there any way, to do this?

Comment: And your problem is ... ?

Comment: I get an array. How to turn it back into source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Formatting largely* goes out the window when doing lexical analysis. It is irrelevant to the logical structure and not preserved. You could reformat those tokens into new source code according to your favourite formatting rules, but you cannot preserve the original source formatting this way.

* There's the `T_WHITESPACE` token which is parsed and returned, however it doesn't look like all whitespace turns into tokens under all circumstances, so you'll probably lose at least some.

If you'd want to do this, you'd either have to write your own tokeniser/parser which also remembers the formatting, or you need to somehow reverse engineer your changes into the source code and modify the original files directly (which sounds like madness, IMO).

Answer (score 2):

I made this code:

```
private static function convertSourceCodeToTestable ($sourceCodePath)
{
    $newCode = '';
    foreach (token_get_all(file_get_contents($sourceCodePath)) as $item)
    {
        if (is_array($item))
        {
            switch ($item[0])
            {
                case T_FINAL :
                case T_STATIC :
                    $item[1] = '';
                    break;
                case T_PRIVATE :
                case T_PROTECTED :
                    $item[1] = 'public';
                    break;
            }
            $item = $item[1];
        }
        $newCode.= $item;
    }
    return $newCode;
}
```

this looks do what I want and wont mess up the code

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the new file using the values in the tokens. No formatting required. Just stitch them together into a string and save it to a file. Just be sure to use is_string() to recognize whether the token is an array or just a string.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to analyze a source code [...] make some modification (for example, turning all private to public, get rid of final, etc

Great, we have the tools to do this.

> (with token_get_all())

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

You rather want to use https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser

> and save the source code

That's a feature of nikic/PHP-Parser indeed.

```
use PhpParser\ParserFactory;
use PhpParser\PrettyPrinter;

$parser = (new ParserFactory())->createForNewestSupportedVersion();
$ast = $parser->parse($code);
// manipulate the AST
...
// print it
$prettyPrinter = new PrettyPrinter\Standard;
echo $prettyPrinter->prettyPrintFile($ast);
```

> but keeping the same formatting, tabulators, etc. Is there any way, to do this?

Formatting is by and large will be lost. If it kept to coding standards before then https://phpqa.io/projects/phpcbf.html could be utilized to restore standards formatted code. Some comments might be lost, see https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/issues/762