# php ob_start with function that uses die?

Tags: php, die, ob-start

I have the following code:

```
function a(){ die( 'some text' ) }
ob_start();
a();
$return = ob_get_clean();
echo 'result:'
var_dump( $return );
```

and it doesn't work.

I get `some text` in my browser.

How can I make it work? How can I catch `die()` in a buffered function?

PS: I cannot change the function.

What should I use instead of ob_start() ?

I tried to run the following code:

```
register_shutdown_function( function() {
    $message = ob_get_contents(); //Capture 'Doh'
    ob_end_clean(); //Cleans output buffer
} );
ob_start();
die( 'works' );
ob_end_clean();
```

and it didn't work...

Comment: Why are you surprised? ob_start turns on output buffering. Your script dies before getting the buffer contents and printing it.

Comment: *Terminates execution of the script* <- You can't catch it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I catch exit() and die() messages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836524/can-i-catch-exit-and-die-messages)